# What type of works are the subject of 17 U.S.C. § 121 (i.e., copyright imitations on exclusive rights for people with disabilities)?

Tags: copyright

The full text of [17 U.S.C. § 121 a) and b)](https://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml?req=granuleid:USC-prelim-title17-section121&num=0&edition=prelim) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20201108020546/https://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml?req=granuleid%3AUSC-prelim-title17-section121&num=0&edition=prelim)) (emphasis mine):

> **§121. Limitations on exclusive rights: Reproduction for blind or other people with disabilities**
>
> a. Notwithstanding the provisions of section 106, it is not an
> infringement of copyright for an authorized entity to reproduce or to
> distribute in the United States **copies or phonorecords of a
> previously published literary work or of a previously published
> musical work** that has been fixed in the form of text or notation if
> such copies or phonorecords are reproduced or distributed in
> accessible formats exclusively for use by eligible persons.
>
> (b)(1) Copies or phonorecords to which this section applies shall-
>
> (A) not be reproduced or distributed in the United States in a format
> other than an accessible format exclusively for use by eligible
> persons;
>
> (B) bear a notice that any further reproduction or distribution in a
> format other than an accessible format is an infringement; and
>
> (C) include a copyright notice identifying the copyright owner and the
> date of the original publication.

The way I understand it:

- **copies of a literary work**
  meaning books, training materials, periodicals, etc. transcribed and distributed in Braille, for example
- **phonorecords of a literary work**
  which would be a sound recording of a published (as in printed) literary work distributed on a medium only used by eligible people. For example, newspaper and magazine articles recorded by volunteers for an audio/radio reading service (such as the [Telephone Reader Program](https://www.brailleinstitute.org/books-for-visually-impaired/telephone-reader-program) at the Braille Institute)

Based on the above, this is how I would interpret the following scenarios:

#### 1. NPR article accompanied by the audio version

The article itself is a literary work so I assume going ahead with that would be ok, but the audio is a sound recording and thus §121 does not apply.

#### 2. Commercial audiobooks

Distributing this would be a no-no, because it is a sound recording (and not a copy or a phonorecord of a literary work), but converting the source literary work would be okay, I guess.

Or, distribution would be alright if the copyright owner provides explicit permission to do so. (The way [the NLS does it](https://www.loc.gov/nls/about/organization/laws-regulations/marrakesh-treaty/#:%7E:text=It%20will%20not%20share%20commercial%20audiobooks%20unless%20the%20publisher%20grants%20permission).)

#### 3. Work is registered as a sound recording, with an underlying literary work

Does this mean that if, for example, a training material includes text and audio, and is registered as audio recording, then §121 would not apply?

Is this scenario the same as 1. above?

---

### Appendix

#### Sound recordings including underlying work

https://www.copyright.gov/register/sr-choose.html

> **When to Use Form SR (Sound Recordings)** Use Form SR for registration of published or unpublished sound recordings, that is,
> for registration of the particular sounds or recorded performance.
>
> Form SR must also be used if you wish to make one registration for
> both the sound recording and the underlying work (the musical
> composition, dramatic, or literary work). You may make a single
> registration only if the copyright claimant is the same for both the
> sound recording and the underlying work. In this case, the authorship
> statement in Space 2 should specify that the claim covers both works.
>
> Form SR is also the appropriate form for registration of a multimedia
> kit that combines two or more kinds of authorship including a sound
> recording (such as a kit containing a book and an audiocassette).

https://www.copyright.gov/eco/help-type.html

> **Sound Recording** Select Sound Recording if you are registering a sound recording. Also, select Sound Recording if you are registering
> both a sound recording and the underlying musical, dramatic, or
> literary work(s) that is embodied in that recording. Note: To register
> both the sound recording and the work embodied in that recording on
> one application, the copyright claimant must own all rights in both
> works.
>
> Note: Under the copyright law, the sounds that accompany a motion
> picture or other audiovisual work are not considered a sound
> recording. Select Motion Picture/Audiovisual as the “Type of Work” to
> register the sounds accompanying a motion picture or an audiovisual
> work.

#### Definitions according to [17 U.S.C. § 101](https://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml?req=granuleid:USC-prelim-title17-section101&num=0&edition=prelim) ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20201107155724/https://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml?req=granuleid%3AUSC-prelim-title17-section101&num=0&edition=prelim))

> "Phonorecords" are material objects in which sounds, other than those
> accompanying a motion picture or other audiovisual work, are fixed by
> any method now known or later developed, and from which the sounds can
> be perceived, reproduced, or otherwise communicated, either directly
> or with the aid of a machine or device. The term "phonorecords"
> includes the material object in which the sounds are first fixed.

> "Sound recordings" are works that result from the fixation of a series
> of musical, spoken, or other sounds, but not including the sounds
> accompanying a motion picture or other audiovisual work, regardless of
> the nature of the material objects, such as disks, tapes, or other
> phonorecords, in which they are embodied.

> "Literary works" are works, other than audiovisual works, expressed in
> words, numbers, or other verbal or numerical symbols or indicia,
> regardless of the nature of the material objects, such as books,
> periodicals, manuscripts, phonorecords, film, tapes, disks, or cards,
> in which they are embodied.

Answer (score 1):

The crucial term here is the last words of 121: ***exclusively** for use by eligible persons.* The created piece must be for the exclusive use of the disabled. For example, a Braile transcription is rather easily *in* that exception, as it is almost illegible for the vast majority of seeing people, and only needs to come in a box that has the needed stickers of the original copyright and that one may not copy or re-convert.

Another thing that this applies to is *phonorecords*. These are physical items that carry audio in a way that it can be reproduced by a machine. Typically in these days those are CDs, Cassettes, or Vinyl, but in the past, [Reel-to-Reel magnetic tape](https://youtu.be/5KHSz9Gi-II), [shellac](https://youtu.be/6YF1w77mbec?t=172) (there's a sound difference to Vinyl), [wax cylinders](https://youtu.be/4wtifAGsV3k) and even [Punchcards](https://youtu.be/399UPZVki1Q) have been used as phonorecords. It's unclear if a flash drive could be a phonorecord, but I tend towards "no, unless it is a Read-Only-Memory".

As you observed, that exception **only** provides for phonorecords and copies, not the actual audio or digital files. This might be an old remnant, but it requires that a copy for the disabled has a physical manifestation that may not be copied again and only is to be given to eligible people. A file on a computer does not satisfy these rules. The Radio program for the disabled uses a *different* exception.

So for a textbook with audio to comply, it has to come in a physical manner and with the files on a labeled phonorecord that contains the prescribed labeling for "Do not copy" and the original copyright.